# How to add Value data from regedit in variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I have registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyLocation` and inside i have string value called Place with data value `Server123` 
How can i add this data value `Server123` to variable using batch file commands (cmd)?

I am trying with below code but it does not save data value in MyVariable:

```
set Path=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyLocation
set StrVal=Place

set MyVariable=
for /f %%a in ('reg query %Path% /v %StrVal% ^| findstr %StrVal%') do (
    set MyVariable=%%b
)

echo MyVariable
```

Comment: Investigate the `reg` command. If you cannot get it to work, copy and paste your code into the question. At that point, someone may have a suggestion.

Comment: I found the problem. The data value was empty and that is why it was not working

Comment: Please **don't** use `Path` as a variable name. It's already a system variable that tells 'cmd'  where to find it's executables.

Answer (score 0):

```
set myPath="HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyLocation"
set StrVal="Place"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query %Path% /v %StrVal%') do (
set myVariable=%%a
)
echo %myVariable%
```

1- Change **`Path`** to **`myPath`** or other name (`Path` from language syntax)
2-Always use quotation marks around your string (avoid space problem)
3-Change **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`**   to   **`HKLM`**  (stick recommended syntax of write code as Microsoft give in help)
4-User **`tokens=3`** instead of **`find /i %StrVal%`** (useless it just give the name of `Place` not the data value inside `place`)
5-To retrieve the value of `MyVariable` you have to add it between  `%MyVariable%`